# C# Namespace Alias qualifier (::) vs Dereferencing Operator (.)

Tags: c#, namespaces, global, dereference

Quick and simple question. I kind of understand what the Namespace Alias qualifier does, it's for accessing members in a namespace, however so does the dereferencing operator. I am really baffled as to the difference in this situation, why you would use one over the other, or how they each accomplish the same thing.

```
using colAlias = System.Collections;

namespace myns
{
    class TestApp
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            colAlias.Hashtable test = new colAlias.Hashtable();
            colAlias::Hashtable test1 = new colAlias::Hashtable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Just because I've been programming in C# for a few years now and I've never seen this operator used anywhere. :D

Comment: @Tudor Same situation here :)
Very rarely seen, but I ran across it today and wanted to learn more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a corner case `::` (like the `@` prefix) is there to deal with the fairly rare occurrences where a name conflicts between namespaces, classes and keywords.

`::` only works for namespaces (and namespace aliases), while `.`. works for both namespaces and subclasses. Most places where you'd need it you'd be better off using a different name instead, but that isn't always an option.

`global::` is a special case that's most often seen in auto-generated code - it resets the referenced namespace to the root.

For instance, suppose you auto-generate some code (maybe for a forms app, EF, or similar) and your app uses the namespace `YourCompany.Application`. Now one of your customers (using your auto-generation) decides to add their own namespace in their app `TheirCompany.YourCompany.Application`. Now all *your* auto code fails because when it compiles .Net doesn't know whether to use your namespace or theirs.

To fix this generate code with `global::YourCompany.Application`, then those that use your auto-generator can use whatever namespace they like and not conflict.

I think Microsoft added `global::` because they expected some .Net customers to add namespaces like `System`.

Comment: _I think Microsoft added global:: because ..._ Not exactly: "You might have to reference two versions of assemblies that have the same fully-qualified type names"

Answer (score 6):

You said:

> Namespace Alias qualifier does, it's for accessing members in a **namespace**, however so does the dereferencing operator.

Well, no. The `.` operator is used to access any member, including functions. You **cannot** do `Console::WriteLine();`

`::` is only for resolving namespaces, either from a namespace alias like this:

```
using colAlias = System.Collections;
...
...
colAlias::Hashtable test = new colAlias::Hashtable();
```

**OR** from global.

```
global::System.Console.WriteLine(..);
```

You **cannot** do :

```
System.Collections::ArrayList a = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
```

BUT, if you have an alias the `.` operator also works, so **in your case**, there is no difference.

Comment: Does this mean that the `.` operator can do everything the `::` operator can and more, except for referencing the global namespace?

Answer (score 2):

There's an [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explaining how this works.

Basically, in your situation they will achieve the same thing and for code readability it's preferred to use a single `.`.

I wouldn't use the `::` operator on anything but the global namespace, and even then there are more than enough ways to work around it.

edit: More information what the operator does is explained at the [:: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx) article.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea of a namespace qualifier is to allow you reference the namespace even if the name has been used elsewhere. If you declared a class named "colAlias" then colAlias.Hashtable would reference the class but colAlias::Hashtable would reference the namespace'd value.

This is a fairly narrow use-case and `global::` is the only typical use case I have seen for this operator (When trying to ensure no conflicts can occur when creating generated code to be compiled in an unknown application).

Answer (score 0):

The namespace alias qualifier (::) helps you to access namespace methods without causing errors if you have CONFLICTING namespaces using the same naming convention.

For example as explained here in msdn
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Well thanks for the answer, but I figured that much myself, read my description.
What I wanted to know were the differences, and for example, why you couldn't use the dereferencing operator to access the global namespace... why you would use one over the other...

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera Suppose you have your own System class. In this case how would you use the dereferencing operator to access System.Console.WriteLine if you wanted to ? 

So you use the namespace alias qualifier to access the global namespace (
global::System.Console.WriteLine() )
in order to avoid the conflict.