# All System namespaces are undefined in project

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, namespaces, system

The problem is the application refrences a solution project whose namespace has a **'System'** in it. The namespace goes something like **'SolutionNamespace.WhatItIs.System'**. So when I build the WPF application, its MainWindow.g.vb and Application.g.vb would give off errors like the following:

- Type 'System.Windows.Window is undefined.
- Type 'System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector

I understand that '*.g.vb' source codes are auto-generated. But is there a way to configure the generator so it could add a **'Global'** to every **'System'** namespaces? Or is there a way to resolve this problem? I can't really change the namespace of the other library the WPF application references since I don't own it. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
I tried changing the `SolutionNamespace.WhatItIs.System` to `SolutionNamespace.WhatItIs.Systems` to see whether my assumptions are correct... I was wrong. `System` namespaces are still undefined and still asking me to change them into `Global.System`.

**Edit II:**
It appears that my assumptions were correct after all. The first time I tried changing `SolutionNamespace.WhatItIs.System` to `SolutionNamespace.WhatItIs.Systems`, I did not modify its Assembly name and Root name properties. When I changed them and rebuilt, the errors were gone. Problem now is if the owner of `SolutionNamespace.WhatItIs.System` would allow me to change the namespace since other projects use it.

Comment: I'd suggest that you have a look at that project and see what they've done in it because I think that they would have had to overcome the same issue.

Comment: If you're referring to the project with the System namespace, then, I do have the its source codes, but I can't change the namespace since other projects are also referencing it.

Comment: Try to remove `Imports SolutionNamespace.WhatItIs.System` if you added that and use a fully qualified name for objects from that namespace instead

Comment: I did not import `SolutionNamespace.WhatItIs.System` because I really can't since MainWindow.g.vb is auto-generated and even if I modify it, it will still be replaced when the project is built again. But when I check the MainWindow.g.vb source code and hover on one of the underlined errors, it's asking me to change `System.Windows.Window` (and other namespaces under System) to `Global.System.Windows.Window`.

Comment: Here is a MSDN article that might help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. It's probably why it's asking to change System to Global.System but the problem is I can't really control the MainWindow.g.vb since it's auto generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either try to use an alias when you add your `using` declarations:

```
using CustomSystem = SolutionNamespace.WhatItIs.System;
```

And then refer to those members like this:

```
CustomSystem.SomeClass = new CustomSystem.SomeClass();
```

Or just not add it to the `using` declarations and fully qualify each use:

```
SolutionNamespace.WhatItIs.System.SomeClass = 
    new SolutionNamespace.WhatItIs.System.SomeClass();
```

---

UPDATE >>>

If that doesn't help, you could take a look at the [Namespace collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262469/namespace-collisions) and [C# Namespace Alias qualifier (::) vs Dereferencing Operator (.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153978/c-sharp-namespace-alias-qualifier-vs-dereferencing-operator) posts here on StackOverflow, which have good answers. I think that @Zache could be correct in mentioning that you might need to use the [Global Namespace Alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chwe1tc8.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I could do that (I probably would) but I don't really have a problem with SolutionNamespace.WhatItIs.System objects. I only have a problem with the auto-generated MainWindow.g.vb which WPF generates on build. I can't really control that part.

Comment: MainWindow.g.vb is generated dependant on your code in the MainWindow.vb file. If you reference the namespaces from that dll properly there, you shouldn't have a problem in the MainWindow.g.vb file.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'm really new to WPF so I have no idea how it really works. And I don't really have the time to study it thoroughly.

Comment: You're welcome, but don't expect that the StackOverflow community will do all of your work for you because you *don't really have the time to study it thoroughly*... we're here to help with specific problems, not to teach new languages. Good luck with the rest of your project.

Comment: I'm actually using MVVM so my MainWindow.xaml.vb basically empty and it doesn't import SolutionNamespace.WhatItIs.System. I have tried importing it with an alias though, just to see if it would remove the error. But the error still shows.