# ASP.Net prompting to change System references to Global.System references

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am a new developer and I am not sure how I have broken my application. My asp.net application has somehow lost reference to the System library. When I build it throws hundreds of errors and every error asks me to change any System reference to a Global.System reference. Such as:

```
Error   4   Type 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' is not defined.
```

This is not specific to any child of System, it's every System reference on any piece of code in the whole application.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for Web with a Target Framework of 4.5. [Here is an image of my "references" portion of the my solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm0jr.png)

The System.dll file is present in that location. Please advise.

**EDIT** I think Mark was on the right path, I simply created a new project and added the relevant existing items into the new project. This removed whatever conflict I inadvertently created.

Comment: Sounds similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158950/all-system-namespaces-are-undefined-in-project) - see if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you, he does sound like he's having a similar issue to me. Forgive me, I'm a bit uneducated when it comes to this portion of visual studio.  I don't understand at all what he is referencing regarding changing from System to Systems or to being the owner of it. It's just the .dll that came with Visual Studio, nothing custom written by anyone here...

Comment: I think the root cause of the issue in the linked question was that there was another namespace with the "System" somewhere in the name - in their case in a referenced DLL, but perhaps it could also be in the same project.  Check that there isn't a namespace with System as part of it's name somewhere.